# Display child elements constrained to parent element

Tags: html, css, display

Say I have a button positioned inside a div:

```css
.parentDiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #B9DEED;
}

.childButton {
  position: absolute;
  left: 90px;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentDiv">
  <button class="childButton">Childbutton</button>
</div>
```

This gets rendered like so:

[image: Button goes out the div's boundaries]

Is there a way to display the button so that it is constrained to the div, i.e. it gets cut off after the "C"?

Comment: overflow:hidden to parent?

Comment: I made you a snippet

Comment: When you it gets cut-off after the letter C. Why is the button used at the first place with text ChildButton. Put only letter C and postion:absolute. I mean we can do whatever you want. But Is there a specific reason that you want to show only C from the button. But with full textContent on it :)

Comment: @mplungjan : Could you also add an output image :) That you trying to get

Comment: Dear Friend I checked your code snippet and ran it also :) What I wanted to say is : Are you looking for some kind of transition with the button later on. Do we really need to keep the text so bigger initially or with "C" letter only in the button it could have done it.. :) So anyways... I hope here are a lots of answers given by experts ... See if that solves your query Mate... Stay Blessed :)

Comment: You don't need to get annoyed. We are here to help you.... People make things with output in their minds. My question was simply to know what was the final outcome image you want to achieve :) It's coding...Making and Breaking things. What is annoying about it....

Comment: @mplungjan : It's you Questioning Sir, I thought it's the questioner. Hi and Happy New year.. Hope you understood where I was coming from in this case :) We are friends ... You have great contributions to the SO community... Salute to you :)

Comment: I was not annoyed, just did not know what you meant. Please direct your questions to CheeseCrustery who asked the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a button positioned inside a div, that's a button (that happens to be child of a div) positioned within the page. For the button to positioned within the div, the div needs to be positioned itself.

Once the parent has position, the `overflow: hidden` will start to work.

```css
div {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 90px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Sample</h3>
<div>
  <button>Childbutton</button>
</div>
```

Core take-away: `position` is always related to the closest ancestor (it does not have to be the direct parent) that has `position`. If there is none, it is related to the page. Setting `position: relative` on a parent establishes a frame of reference without taking the parent out of the document flow.

You can see the difference if you set `top: 10px` on the button. Try with and without `position: relative` on the div to verify the frame of reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the style `overflow: hidden` to hide everything outside the parent-element.

This does, however, not apply to `position: absolute` elements. You would need to use `position. relative` for that.